# which one is right？Thank you

Tags: sentence

I saw in her eyes the love to me.
In her eyes，I saw the love to me.

please tell me  do these two sentences have the same meaning? Which is more often said?

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, as an American, I would tend to think that "for" is a better (more natural) choice than "to" would be in these example sentences:

Thus, **"I saw in her eyes the love for me."** or **"In her eyes, I saw the love for me."**

The two sentences above seem to emphasize slightly different things, but are very similar in meaning and will both be understood.

Answer (score -3):

I saw in her eyes the love to me - - - This sentence is more relevant if we take into account the actual definition of "sentence".

Comment: Both sentences have the same meaning, but neither would be used. There aren't multiple loves in her eyes, so 'the' isn't needed.  The love belongs to her, so it is 'her love', and that love does not really move, so it is her love 'for' (or 'of') you.

Comment: What is "the actual definition of *sentence*", pray tell? Please specify.